# how to get nested json data at column level in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am very new to extjs, i have strucked hear about one day, please any one do help.

How do I get nested json data at column level in extjs
For normal columns its getting exactly, but when it cums to array column at col6 was strucked.

this is how my model looks like

json data like:

```
[
       {
       "col1" : "abc",
       "col2" : "aasd",
       "col3" : "aasd",
       "col4" : "sad",
       "col5" : "sad",
       "col6" : [
                   {
                      "inncol1": "laksd",
                      "inncol2": "laksd"
                   },
                   {
                      "inncol1": "laksd",
                      "inncol2": "laksd"
                   }
                   ]
       },

        {
       "col1" : "abc",
       "col2" : "aasd",
       "col3" : "aasd",
       "col4" : "sad",
       "col5" : "sad",
       "col6" : [
                   {
                      "inncol1": "laksd",
                      "inncol2": "laksd"
                   },
                   {
                      "inncol1": "laksd",
                      "inncol2": "laksd"
                   }
                   ]
       }

    ]
```

Expecting outpoot :

```
====================================================================
**col1**    **col2**    **col3**    **col4**    **col5**                **col6  **
                                            ========================            
                                             **inncol1**    **inncol2** 
====================================================================
abc     jasd    asjd    aasd    asdjk        asdjk        asdas
                                             asdas         asdd
=====================================================================
asdas   sada    asdas   sdf     asdas       asdas           sdaas
                                            asds            daass
======================================================================
```

Model is :

```
 Ext.define('MONTHWISEMODEL', 
                            {
                                extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
                                fields  :
                                [
                                     {  name: 'col1'                }
                                    ,{  name: 'col2'                }
                                    ,{  name: 'col3'                }
                                    ,{  name: 'col4'                }
                                    ,{  name: 'col5'                }
                                    ,{  name: 'col6'                }
                                ]
                            });
```

Store is :

```
getStore : function()
            {
                var proxy = {
                         type        : 'ajax'
                        ,url         : myurl
                        ,reader      : 'jsonreader'

                return   Ext.create('Ext.data.GridStore',
                            {
                                 model      : 'MONTHWISEMODEL'
                                ,autoLoad   : false
                                ,autoDestroy: false
                                ,proxy      : proxy
                            });
            }   
    }
```

Grid is :

```
getMonthlyReportGrid : function()
    {

        var me = this;
        var store = me.getStore();
        var reportsGrid =   Ext.create('Ext.custom.grid.Panel', 
        {
             store          : store
            ,id             : 'monthlyGridData'
            ,overflowX      : 'scroll' 
            ,overflowY      : 'scroll'
            ,forceFit       : false
            ,height         : 450
            ,cls            : 'pr-data-grid'
            ,columns        : 
                [
                     {  text : 'col1'                               ,dataIndex : 'col1'             }
                    ,{  text : 'col2'                               ,dataIndex : 'col2'             }
                    ,{  text : 'col3'                               ,dataIndex : 'col3'             }
                    ,{  text : 'col4'                               ,dataIndex : 'col4'                 }
                    ,{  text : 'col5'                               ,dataIndex : 'col5'             }
                    ,{  text : 'col6'                                , columns: [                                                   
                                                                                    ,{ text : 'inncol1'       ,dataIndex : 'inncol1'            }
                                                                                    ,{ text : 'inncol2'       ,dataIndex : 'inncol2'        }
                                                                                ] }
                ]

        });
        return reportsGrid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [renderer](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer) method of `Ext.grid.column.Column` class, which can be used as a converter where you return the value you wish. Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l2l)

Comment: Thank you very much, that works fine, is there any possibility to make separate rows with in the same row as same like header instead of 'br' line